# Microsoft NMake Target Specific Variable Values

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, nmake

Using gnu make, I can define target specific variable values like this:

```
release : CFLAGS = -std=c99 -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing
```

Is there a similar feature for Microsoft NMake?

Comment: There is no such feature for Microsoft NMake.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I suspected since I couldn't find anything in my searches. I'll just use different variables for each target.